# Accentuation in R

Tags: r, encoding, diacritics

I was wonderiing if there exist a short way to get accents of a character string in R. For instance when I the "accentued" string is "Université d'Aix-Marseille" with my script I get "Universit%C3A9 d%27Aix-Marseille". Is there any function or algorithm to get the former one directly ?

I precise tht the file from where a get all my character string is encoded is UTF-8.

Sincerely yours.

Comment: The display of accentuated characters depends on the encoding of the file and your R session `options("encoding")`.

Comment: when executing the command it shows me "native.enc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and set the encoding of a character vector like this:

```
s <- "Université d'Aix-Marseille"
Encoding(s)

# set encoding to utf-8
Encoding(s) <- "UTF-8"
s
```

If that fixes it, you could change your default encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: this don't work directly, when I do "Encoding(s)" it gave me "latin 1", then when I change it in my script for UTF-8 or latin1 the accents stay written that crazy way.

Comment: what does this return: Sys.getlocale() ?

Comment: LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252

Comment: does this work? iconv("Université d'Aix-Marseille", "Windows-1252", "UTF-8")